# Joining to a table with multiple rows for the join item

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table `users` which has a primary key `userid` and a datetime column `pay_date`.

I've also got a table `user_actions` which references `users` via the column `userid`, and a datetime column `action_date`.

I want to join the two tables together, fetching only the earliest action from the `user_actions` table which has an `action_date` later than or equal to `pay_date`.

I'm trying things like:

```
select users.userid from users
left join user_actions on user_actions.userid = users.userid
where user_actions.action_date >= users.pay_date
order by user_actions.pay_date
```

But obviously that returns me multiple rows per user (one for every user action occurring on or after `pay_date`). Any idea where to go from here?

Apologies for what probably seems like a simple question, I'm fairly new to t-sql.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a `PRIMARY KEY` on `user_actions`:

```
SELECT  u.*, ua.*
FROM    users u
LEFT JOIN
        user_actions ua
ON      user_actions.id = 
        (
        SELECT  TOP 1 id
        FROM    user_actions uai
        WHERE   uai.userid = u.userid
                AND uai.action_date >= u.pay_date
        ORDER BY
                uai.action_date
        )
```

If you don't:

```
WITH    j AS
        (
        SELECT  u.*, ua.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ua.userid ORDER BY ua.action_date) AS rn, ua.action_date
        FROM    users u
        LEFT JOIN
                user_actions ua
        ON      ua.userid = u.userid
                AND ua.action_date >= u.pay_date
        )
SELECT  *
FROM    j
WHERE   rn = 1 or action_date is null
```

**Update:**

`CROSS APPLY` proposed by `@AlexKuznetsov` is more elegant and efficient.

Comment: Does that assume the user_Actions table has an id?

Comment: The first solutions does (as the post says), the second one does not.

Comment: Thanks - that's almost exactly what I want. Is it possible to keep users with whom no such action exists? I only want one value (`ua.action_date`) out of the `user_actions` table, and I'd like that to be null if no such action exists. No worries if you've not got time, you answered my question perfectly, so I've +1ed you, and will mark your answer accepted regardless.

Comment: @Dominic: sure, just replace JOIN with LEFT JOIN

Comment: @Quassnoi - replacing JOIN with LEFT JOIN will only pull you back the first row in `users` for which there are no `user_actions` (since `rn=1`), adding `or ua.action_date is null` did the trick.

Answer (score 5):

CROSS APPLY is your friend:

```
select users.*, t.* from users
CROSS APPLY(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM user_actions WHERE user_actions.userid = users.userid
AND user_actions.action_date >= users.pay_date
order by user_actions.pay_date) AS t
```

Comment: This is a fair bit slower than @Quassnoi's suggestion, and doesn't account for `users` with no `user_actions`. Answers the original question though, so +1!

Answer (score 0):

```
select u.*, ua.* from
    users u join users_actions ua on u.userid = ua.userid
where
    ua.action_date in
            (select min(action_date) from user_actions ua1
             where
                  ua1.action_date >= u.pay_date and
                  u.userid=ua1.userid)
```